# XPath 1.0 count number of nodes based on children conditions

Tags: xml, xpath

I need to count the number of certain nodes in an XML tree until a node with a specific child is found.

A sample of my XML looks like this:

```
<w:body>
    <w:p w:rsidR="00680C51" w:rsidRDefault="00680C51">
      <w:r>
        <w:t xml:space="preserve">This is </w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:proofErr w:type="spellStart"/>
      <w:r>
        <w:t>outside</w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:proofErr w:type="spellEnd"/>
    </w:p>
    <w:p w:rsidR="00680C51" w:rsidRDefault="00680C51"/>
    <w:p w:rsidR="00680C51" w:rsidRDefault="00680C51">
      <w:pPr>
        <w:sectPr w:rsidR="00680C51">
          <w:pgSz w:w="11906" w:h="16838"/>
          <w:pgMar w:top="1701" w:right="1134" w:bottom="1701" w:left="1134" w:header="708" w:footer="708" w:gutter="0"/>
          <w:cols w:space="708"/>
          <w:docGrid w:linePitch="360"/>
        </w:sectPr>
      </w:pPr>
    </w:p>
    <w:p w:rsidR="00680C51" w:rsidRPr="00680C51" w:rsidRDefault="00680C51">
      <w:pPr>
        <w:rPr>
          <w:lang w:val="en-US"/>
        </w:rPr>
      </w:pPr>
      <w:bookmarkStart w:id="1" w:name="Reminder"/>
      <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="1"/>
      <w:r w:rsidRPr="00680C51">
        <w:rPr>
          <w:lang w:val="en-US"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t>Reminder</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
</w:body>
```

What I need to do is to create a query which counts how many `w:p` nodes which have a children node called `w:sectPr` are above a certain `w:p` node which has a children node called `w:bookmarkStart` with a given `name` attribute

For example the result of the query for this particular case is 1.

In XPath 2.0 I am using the following query:

```
count(//w:bookmarkStart[@w:name = "Reminder"]/ancestor::w:p[1]/preceding-sibling::w:p[*/w:sectPr])]
```

The problem is that I don't know how to this in XPath 1.0.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Apart from the typo (trailing `]` character), that should work fine in XPath 1.0.

Comment: Even with the typo fixed, In Xpath 1.0 I still get this error which says that "Only child and attribute axes are allowed outside predicates".

Comment: I could be wrong, but it doesn't seem like an XPath 1.0 issue. What tool are you using to evaluate this?

Comment: I think I missed a very important aspect, the query is used in XSLT

Comment: it would be something like that .. I'm using the position() .. count(//w:p[*/w:sectPr and position() <  //w:p[*/w:bookmarkStart[@w:name = "Reminder"][1]/position()])

Comment: Andy, @salathe is right, your XPath expression (except the last `]`) is fine, both in XPath 1.0 and in XPath 2.0. Nothing has changed from 1.0 to 2.0 regarding the constructs you use in the expression. If this is used in XSLT, please show that stylesheet (a [minimal one](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), that is) - the one that throws the error you have described in the comments. Also, show _well-formed_ XML input, add the missing namespace declaration.

Comment: Thank you for your advise @MathiasMüller and sorry for the late response, but the XSLT was pretty big and since I don't have so much knowledge in the subject I've decided not to post it (the XSLT was made by one of my colleagues and he guaranteed its functionality). Anyway, I've managed to find the answer that I was looking for and I will post below.

Answer (score 0):

The answer that I came up with looks like this

```
count(//w:body/*[following-sibling::node()[self::*[descendant-or-self::w:bookmarkStart[@w:name="Reminder"]]]]/*[w:sectPr])
```

Basically I am finding the `bookmarkStart` that I am looking for then I am going back on the XML tree and I select the nodes which contain `sectPr`.

In XSLT this works as a charm.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7982985/why-doesnt-xslt-like-my-xpath-query) post helped me understand what is happening exactly